# ASP.NET CORE Adding Business Logic to Model instead of Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

In ASP.NET CORE I have my logic and calculations in my `controller` but I know that having skinny `controllers` and fat `models` is the typical approach.  Here is my model

```
public class Yearly
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public decimal Q1Rev {get;set;}
    public decimal Q2Rev {get;set;}
    public decimal Q3Rev {get;set;}
    public decimal Q4Rev {get;set;}
    public decimal Q1Cost {get;set;}
    public decimal Q2Cost {get;set;}
    public decimal Q3Cost {get;set;}
    public decimal Q4Cost {get;set;}
    public decimal Q1Profit {get;set;}
    public decimal Q2Profit {get;set;}
    public decimal Mean {get;set}
}
```

In the `Create` method of `controller`

```
Yearly yearly = new Yearly
{
    Q1Rev = yearly.Q1Rev,
    Q2Rev = yearly.Q2Rev,
    Q3Rev = yearly.Q3Rev,
    Q4Rev = yearly.Q4Rev,
    Q1Cost = yearly.Q1Cost,
    Q2Cost = yearly.Q2Cost,
    Q3Cost = yearly.Q3Cost,
    Q4Cost = yearly.Q4Cost,
    Q1Profit = yearly.Q1Rev - Q1Cost,
    Q2Profit = yearly.Q2Rev - yearly.Q2Cost,
    Mean = (yearly.Q1Profit + yearly.Q2Profit) / 2
};
```

How can add the calulations into the `model` rather than in the `Create` method of the `controller`? Or should I leave it in the `controller`?

Answer (score 1):

> but I know that having skinny controllers and fat models is the typical approach.

Ah - NO? Where the heck did you get that one from?

A Model is ONLY there to represent the data model of the view. It actually MAY be reused and composed in parts. There is no sense in putting this into the model.

Look up the definitions of "model" and "controller" in a dictionary. One of them does not even as a hint towards containing logic.

The only logic that may make sense to have in a view, is purely viewish in style - i.e. stuff like formatting output.

I would definitely NOT move them into the controller. Maybe some servie or business class - if, i.e. they are reusable or so complex to validate their own unit tests (i.e. financial calculation often have quite convoluted formulas that you may want to keep in a separate object).

Comment: So possibly put the calculations in a separate object, like their own class? Then reference that in the controller? I ask because it seems inefficient if I have multiple controllers that may calculate 'Mean', to have to calculate it in every controller. Wha twould be best?

Comment: Yeah. Mostly also because you want them to be able to be reused in mutliple applications (so, not class, ocnsider a separate PROJECT) and tested (!).